# Sendmail and hostname config for another domain

Tags: email, sendmail

The following example with fictional names describes my situation:

- External mail service mailservice.com
- DNS entry my.server.com points to the server publicly
- The server should send e-mails from myserver@yetanotherdomain.com

I'm struggling to understand how to name the server (hostname) and what sendmail config to use. Currently, I have the config:

```
# /etc/hostname
some-random-hostname-without-tld
```

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost some-random-hostname-without-tld my.server.com
127.0.1.1   some-random-hostname-without-tld
```

`/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` contains the minimal config for connecting to the account `myserver@yetanotherdomain.com` on `mailservice.com` and defaults otherwise. DNS is setup correctly, i.e. MX, SPF etc. are in place to allow `mailservice.com` to send and receive mails as `yetanotherdomain.com`.

While sending e-mails works with this config, doing so takes over 60 seconds. `/var/log/mail.info` reports that:

- Relay `root@localhost` reports immediately: "Message accepted for delivery"
- Over a minute later, `smtp.mailservice.com` reports: "stat=Sent (Ok: queued as ...)"

The delay indicates that there is something with my config. As stated above, I'm unsure about which domain to use where. Thus, I have the following questions:

- What do I need to assign to `/etc/hosts` as `127.0.0.1` resp. `127.0.1.1`?
- What should the contents of `/etc/hostname` be? Does it have to be something specific or can `/etc/hosts` make up for non-FQDN as hostname?
- Do I need to configure a special host in `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` or is `use_cw_file` good enough in my case?

Comment: Try `openssl s_client -connect smtp.mailservice.example:25 -starttls smtp -crlf` and do the SMTP commands step by step (starting with `EHLO my.server.example`). It may well be your relay just being slow - or your relay failing to lookup your name or IP address and eventually giving up (I could have checked this if I knew the name.. which is why [you should not obfuscate by nature public names in your posts](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts/6063#6063))

Comment: Well, do `hostname -s` and `hostname -f` return expected short and fully-qualified names? What does the manual page for or the relevant section of your OS release notes say about how you should configure `/etc/hosts` (on many systems, you can bring it up using `man 5 hosts`)?

Comment: @anx thank you for your answers. The latter helped me get `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` straight. `man hostname` contains a section "The FQDN" which documents how to set short and full domain name, namely `127.0.1.1 some-random-hostname-without-tld my.server.com`, which causes `hostname -s` and `-f` to work properly. The delay is still there, I will now probe manual connection via openssl.

Comment: Turns out, the mail server does not support STARTTLS. Also, I replaced the `sendmail` setup by `msmtp-mta`, which made configuration significantly easier. Now, mails are sent and delivered instantly.